# MUI Select component with custom children item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a `Select` component with a series of custom items that are mapped through a list. Each item has a specific type and, based on that type, the menu item will have a certain MUI icon. I created a specific component for managing the whole `Select` component and another specific component to display each item, its value and its icon. The problem is that the `onChange` function is not triggered whenever I click on one of the items. What could the problem be?

I'm attaching a code of what I'm doing.

```
const myTypes = {
  TYPE_1: "Type 1",
  TYPE_2: "Type 2",
  TYPE_3: "Type 3",
};

function TypeSelect(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = useState(myTypes.TYPE_1);

  const onChangeType = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      id="select-type"
      value={state}
      onChange={onChangeType}
    >
      {Object.keys(myTypes).map((type) => (
        <TypeSelectMenuItem
          type={myTypes[type]}
          key={type}
        />
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
}

function TypeSelectMenuItem({ type }) {
  const renderIcon = () => {
    switch (type) {
      case myTypes.TYPE_1:
        return <ShortTextIcon />; // Material-UI icon
      case myTypes.TYPE_2:
        return <SubjectIcon />; // Material-UI icon
      case myTypes.TYPE_3:
        return <RadioButtonCheckedIcon />; // Material-UI icon
      default:
        return <Fragment />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <MenuItem value={type} >
      <ListItemIcon>{renderIcon()}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={type} />
    </MenuItem>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the import statements too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to Material-UI [docs](https://mui.com/components/selects/#select), this is how you use the `MenuItem` component to render `Select`'s options:

```js
<Select value={age} onChange={handleChange}>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

When you want to pass a custom component instead of `MenuItem` as `Select` children item. For example `TypeSelectMenuItem`, you need to do the following things:

#### 1. Pass all props to your custom item component

`SelectInput` will clone every child and [attach](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/bcb61849635b44c44c687a11e12a96087d582397/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L307-L308) additional event handlers as extra props behind the scene, so make sure to pass all of them down using spread operator:

```js
const TypeSelectMenuItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem {...props}>
      {...}
    </MenuItem>
  );
};
```

```js
<Select value={state} onChange={onChangeType}>
  {Object.keys(myTypes).map((type) => (
    <TypeSelectMenuItem value={myTypes[type]} key={type}>
      {myTypes[type]}
    </TypeSelectMenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

#### 2. Pass the option value to the `value` props

Do not invent a new props name like what you did here:

```js
<TypeSelectMenuItem type={myTypes[type]} key={type} />
```

The correct way is to pass to `value` instead of `type` props:

```js
<TypeSelectMenuItem value={myTypes[type]} key={type} />
```

The reason is because internally, `SelectInput` references `props.value` instead of your `props.type`. See [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/bcb61849635b44c44c687a11e12a96087d582397/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L155) and [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/bcb61849635b44c44c687a11e12a96087d582397/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L186). Using anything other than `props.value` will lead to unexpected behaviors.

#### 3. Reference `data-value` instead of `value` in your custom component

When cloning item elements, `SelectInput` [set](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/bcb61849635b44c44c687a11e12a96087d582397/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L322) the `value` props to undefined and utilize `data-value` props instead, So you need to use `data-value` props internally:

```js
const TypeSelectMenuItem = (props) => {
  // when passing as children item of Select. props.value is set to undefined.
  // Use props['data-value'] instead.
  return (
    <MenuItem {...props}>
      {...}
      <ListItemText primary={props["data-value"]} />
    </MenuItem>
  );
};
```

#### 4. Pass children to your custom item component to render selected value

`SelectInput` uses [children props](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/bcb61849635b44c44c687a11e12a96087d582397/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L297) to render selected value, so you need to make sure to pass something as children to display:

```js
const TypeSelectMenuItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem {...props}>
      // this is children of MenuItem, so it is not displayed as selected value
      <ListItemIcon>{renderIcon()}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={props["data-value"]} />
    </MenuItem>
  );
};
```

```js
<Select value={state} onChange={onChangeType}>
  {Object.keys(myTypes).map((type) => (
    <TypeSelectMenuItem value={myTypes[type]} key={type}>
      // this is children of TypeSelectMenuItem, so it is displayed as selected value
      {myTypes[type]}
    </TypeSelectMenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66943324/material-ui-select-component-with-custom-children-item]

Comment: That was by far the most complete answer I've ever got, thank you so much!

Comment: @Sosnos you're welcome. Reading source code should be the last solution if the behavior is not documented, but it clears a lot of things if you know where to read.