# How to use MenuItem in a div instead of a direct child to the Select component in MUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to MUI.
I am trying to use `Select` and `MenuItem` together to display a [checked dropdown](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#checkmarks).
However, I want to make a header and a footer and a body div inside select. This body div will have my MenuItems. This doesn't work as [Select expects MenuItems to be its direct child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66943324/mui-select-component-with-custom-children-item). I tried the above link but was unable to make my code work. When I click on checkboxes, nothing happens as the `event.target.value` received by `handleChange` is undefined. How to achieve this?

```
<Select
        labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
        id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
        multiple
        value={personName}
        onChange={handleChange}
        input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
        renderValue={(selected) => { console.log(selected); return selected.join(", ");}}
>

<div>
<div> Sticky header </div>
<div>
    {props.dataArray.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
                    <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
                    <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </MenuItem>
    ))}
</div>
<div> Sticky footer </div>
<div>

</Select>
```

This might be helpful too - [MUI Select custom MenuItem not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68378474/mui-select-custom-menuitem-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
          id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
          renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          <div> Sticky header </div>
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
              <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
          <div> Sticky footer </div>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
```

I tried this code and it worked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This does solve the problem, up to a certain extent. I tried this along with - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70789541/10217754. What happens is when the `names` increases in size, the entire select component becomes scrollable instead of the div with all menu items (which we eliminated). Even when making the header and footer sticky with CSS, they are not fixed and move slightly when scrolling. I wanted to avoid this small movement. Though, this will work. Thanks

Comment: Ok the sticky footer and header but how to add a scrollable container for the Menu list:?

Comment: By scrollable container I mean adding max-height and overflow-y : scroll on the wrapper of the li items, since the li items don't have a wrapper. how can we address that issue?